# use string to verify city returned from reverse geocoding?

Tags: javascript, reverse-geocoding, mapquest

I'm using MapQuest and javascript to reverse geocode latitude and longitude coordinates to verify the city name. I am comparing the result returned with a string "Los Angeles". Is that correct? My code is below

```
latitude = item.latitude;
longitude = item.longitude;


MQA.withModule('geocoder', function() {

/*Executes a geocode with an object containing lat/lng properties, adds result to the    map, and
adds a function to be called once geocoding is complete.*/
map.reverseGeocodeAndAddLocation(
 { lat: latitude, lng: longitude }, processRawData);

/*Example function used to show the address of the geocoded location*/
function processRawData(response) {



 if (response.results.length > 0 && response.results[0].locations.length > 0) {


       var location = response.results[0].locations[0];
       var town = location.adminArea5 + "";
}

if(town == "Los Angeles"){

    inLosAngeles += 1;
}

else {
    notLosAngeles +=1;
}

geoData += 'inLosAngeles=' + inLosAngeles + ',' + 'notLosAngeles' + notLosAngeles +      '</p>';

$('#results').append(geoData);


}

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Is that correct"?  It will only be even potentially correct for locations that are in Los Angeles. Is it working?  What are you trying to do?  What problems are you having?

Comment: I am doing a school project where I am verifying if photos tagged 'losangeles' are really in Los Angeles. I am pulling latitude and longitude from Flickr photos, I get from a json call url, then I am trying to reverse geocode the lat and long to verify if they are in Los Angeles. I know my code is not working because some pictures that are tagged 'losangeles' have lat and long in Europe.

Comment: Each json query to flickr returns 250 results for each page. My count always returns all 250 are in Los Angeles, when that is not the case.

Comment: Why is this tagged google-maps if you are using the MapQuest geocoder?  Have you seen [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_geocoding-reverse2postcodeC.html?address=Los%20Angeles) which uses the Google Maps Javascript API v3 reverse geocoder to extract the "city"?

Comment: I wasn't sure if anyone would respond to just MapQuest tag.

Comment: never do that again. The tags are there for a reason. If you're intentionally using the wrong tag to get more people to look at it, you're wasting all those people's time by lying about what you need help on. Someone with google maps knowledge is in no way expected to have mapquest knowledge.

Comment: Sorry about that. Can the city be verified correctly by comparing to a string?

Comment: Print some debugging output (including the `town` variable and the `response` content) each time you increase either `inLosAngeles` or `notLosAngeles` and you will probably see why you get wrong numbers. Also, you always increase one of these two variables even if the if-condition at the start of the function doesn't match. This seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not putting the result on the map, you can use the [Geocode Web Service reverse geocoder](http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/#reversesample) directly and just compare the city result to "Los Angeles".

```
http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/reverse?key=KEY&callback=compare&location=40.0755,-76.329999
```